# What is this creeper with small flowers and a strange fruit?

Tags: identification, flowers, fruits, vines

This creeper was growing around a tree in our yard. We separated the vines and put them through/around the iron handrail and fence visible in the images below.

The vines are between 2 and 5 metres long, from a plant several years old. They began budding and showing the flowers in the top image, which are a white shading into pink at the centre, with petals between 8 and 25 millimetres long. We have also noticed today the bulk of what appears to be fruit or seed pods, shown in the bottom image. They are a pale to regular green with a surface resembling that of feijoa, and are approximately the same size as that fruit.

What plant is this? What should I be sure to know and do about it?

[image: close-up of some small white and pink flowers on a vine]

[image: close-up of an unknown green fruit growing on a vine]

Comment: what part of the world are you in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be *Araujia hortorum*, also known as *Araujia sericifera*; common names include Moth vine, bladder vine, cruel vine. This plant is toxic to cattle and other animals, including dogs; considered an invasive weed in some countries because the seeds in those fruits germinate fairly easily, [more information is available here](https://www.terrain.net.nz/friends-of-te-henui-group/weeds/moth-plant-araujia-sericifera.html).